# Multiple stir bars have lost their magnetism

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm attempting to produce sodium metal chemically. It is a proven process. It requires 15 hours of heating with continuous stirring. I've run the process 4 times now. Every time the stir bars get demagnetized and of course don't work anymore. I've replaced the stir bars with different sizes, types, and from different manufacturers. Regardless the stir bars inevitably quit working. The temperatures used are 120 C for two hours, and then 200 C for the remainder of the 15 hours. The process calls for quantities of Mg, NaOH, Menthol Crystals, and Mineral Oil. So, that's what the stir bar is stirring. The rate of spin is not high since the stir bar would be thrown to the side of the flask, so the rate is very carefully set. The rate, however, doesn't seem like it would be the issue here.  Does anyone have any information or suggestions. please.

Comment: Heating the bars  causes spontaneous demagnetisation and by reaching the Curie temperature even gaining paramagnetism. Try experimenting with different magnetic materials where these phenomena happen at higher temperature. Consider alternative ways of mixing, if applicable.

Comment: I would thought about the apparatus + heater/heating bath bearing placed on a horizontal linear or circular  shaker. These are used e.g. for large volume extractions or  in pharmaceutical stability studies, simulating tablet dissolution.

Comment: @Poutnik If the Curie temperature is the factor here, then OP must have some poor-quality bars. Usually magnet stirring bars should be good for heating up to at least 350 °C.

Comment: I suppose eventual demagnetization comes before paramagnetic transition, I have mentioned that for completeness. I admit am I not an expert in magnetic properties. @HSChem  Are the bars usable after cooling down again, or is the change permanent ?

Comment: I really appreciate each of the responses. Thank you! For Poutnik's question about bar usability after they've cooled down, my response is they are not usable. They remain demagnetized. It seems illogical to me because the temperature doesn't seem high enough to consistently cause problems. I've used bars from three different manufacturers if I recall correctly. Is there a brand of stir bars that has worked well for anyone.

Comment: It is possible that the stir bars are being *chemically* damaged by the harsh reaction (teflon stir bars, for example, are certainly not compatible with liquid sodium and possibly not with fused alkali at high temperatures). So, if the coating is damaged, the contents might suffer reactions that destroy the magnet.

Comment: Thank you matt_black for your response! It certainly is a consideration and may well be the cause. The mixture of magnesium and sodium hydroxide as a heated solution is destructive. Without making sure the NaOH is very dry the bottom of the flask can be damaged. The stir bars always come out coated with a relatively hard black substance that must be scraped off. A mixture of sulfuric acid and hydrogen peroxide won't touch it after hours of soaking. Do you know if there is a different type of stir bar that might not be affected in this way? Thanks again for everyone's responses!

Comment: The reaction involves "Mg, NaOH, Menthol Crystals, and Mineral Oil." Somehow, I doubt that recipe will make any Na metal! And, as has been mentioned, heat destroys magnets.

Comment: That's what I thought Dr. Moishe Pippik, when I first heard about this process. Then I watched it happening. Here's a link if you're interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsNoiFj3wlw&t=138s                                                   If you do watch the video I'd be interested in your thoughts. Regardless, please accept my appreciation for your response concerning this issue. It means a lot to me for someone to take the time to share their thoughts.